# How can I replace the space character in SVN dump branches name?

Tags: replace

I'd like to replace the space () character(s) in the name of the branches with an underscore (`_`). For example, say I have a *sedtest* file containing:

```
Node-path: trunk/
Node-path: trunk/src/lib 0
Node-path: trunk/src/lib 0/bla.txt
Node-path: branches/ branch0-blabla_blabla/src
Node-path: branches/ branch0-blabla_blabla
Node-path: branches/branch1 stuffthing
Node-path: branches/branch1 stuffthing/src/lib 0
Node-path: branches/branch1 stuffthing/src/lib 0/bla.txt
Node-path: branches/branch2stuffthing/src/lib 0/bl a.txt
```

I'd like it to be modified like this:

```
Node-path: trunk/
Node-path: trunk/src/lib 0
Node-path: trunk/src/lib 0/bla.txt
Node-path: branches/_branch0-blabla_blabla/src
Node-path: branches/_branch0-blabla_blabla
Node-path: branches/branch1_stuffthing
Node-path: branches/branch1_stuffthing/src/lib 0
Node-path: branches/branch1_stuffthing/src/lib 0/bla.txt
Node-path: branches/branch2stuffthing/src/lib 0/bl a.txt
```

I'm having an issue similar as the one described in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33879823/use-regex-with-sed-to-replace-spaces-by-underscore). However, that question requests to replace all the spaces in the path. I'd like to replace the spaces only in the branches names.

From that other question, I have modified the `sed` command to:

```
sed '/^Node-path: branches\//s/ /_/2' < sedtest
```

But it also modifies the last line to `Node-path: branches/branch2stuffthing/src/lib_0/bl a.txt`, which should be left untouched. My experience with `sed` being quite limited, I've been unable to properly limit the 'search region' to what is between `branches/` and the following `/` or `$`, whichever comes first. I'm using CentOS 7.

As for what I'm trying to accomplish: I'm trying to port our SVN repository to a git one, and according to [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3651867/637987) and on my personal experience, git branches names can't have spaces in them. I'm trying to fix this through a svn dump as suggested [on svnbook.red-bean.com](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.filtering).

I suppose I could grep all the faulty branches and manually replace the strings, but that would be less generic, more work, and *much less entertaining*.

Comment: I've been hesitant to tag this with [tag:sed] as I'm not having the issue with `sed` but with replacing the string. If `sed` is the proper tool for the job, that's great! If it's something else, that's great too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have built the following `sed` command:

```
$ sed '/^Node-path: branches\//s/Node-path: branches\/\([-A-Za-z0-9]*\) \
   \([-A-Za-z0-9]*\)/Node-path: branches\/\1_\2/' < sedtest
```

It looks big and ugly, but it works for this situation.

Note that it does not fix multiple occurrences of the space in the branch name, only one (so I will re-run the command if I need).

---

As a side note, if you're doing this to fix an SVN dump, don't forget to fix the `Node-copyfrom-path:` lines the same way.

Comment: I'm still interested in finding a more elegant way to achieve this, if any.

Comment: You don't need the pattern part of `/prefix/ s/prefixmore/result/` -- if you run the `s` command on all lines, it will simply leave unchanged the lines that don't have /prefix/

Comment: Ok, thanks for your comment, I'll try that later tonight!

Answer (score 0):

```
 sed '/^Node-path: branches\/ /s/ /_/2' < sedtest
```

look the space between the two slashes after branches

Comment: I'm afraid this does not work. This will fix the branches that begin with a space, such as `branches/ branch0-blabla_blabla/src`, but will not fix the branch names that have a space in the middle such as `branches/branch1 stuffthing/src/lib 0`.

Answer (score 0):

**Perl lookbehind** makes it a little simpler, though I wouldn't claim much:

```
perl -ple 's:^Node-path: branches/\K([^ /]*) :$1_:' <file
```

or maybe awk, which can handle more than one space in the branchname by changing to gsub:

```
awk -F/ -vOFS=/ '$1=="Node-path: branches"{sub(/ /,"_",$2)} 1' <file
```